# How do i remove double slashes at the end of URL in Google analytic report

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I am trying to use Custom filter in Google Analytics to remove double forward slashes (//)appearing in my reports

**EXAMPLE:** When i am viewing landing page report, i want

*/pagename//*

**To Appear as**

*/pagename/*

**I have tried the following solution**
Filter > Custom > Search Replace > Filter Field > Request URI
added
//$
into the "Search String" field. Then entered
/
into the "Replace String" field.
But that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are evaluating the filter today, you may have to wait for midnight to check if the filter actually worked correctly.

Alternatively if this doesn't work try to use this in Search String field:

```
\/\/
```